# What is the best method for route cost estimation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, google-maps-api, cost-path, distance-matrix

What would be the best method for calculating a rough adhoc route cost i.e. a potential road

(been some years since I have used Network Analysis in ArcGIS), alternatively would it be better using Google Map/ArcGIS Javascript API ..(I am okay with really rough cost)

- Ideally freehand e.g. http://gmap-pedometer.com/ and not just between 2 specific places or abiding by an already set network like network analysis requires
- It would be intelligent i.e above a certain relief the route would be greater in cost per Km (if a tunnel is required), then as it declines below X metres it would resume normal cost per Km

Comment: Network Analyst can do all of that. You can create a cost matrix and then you can run route problems, just set it all up in the properties where you can set your cost to time, distance, or customize with your own scripts.

Comment: GIS SE uses a single, focused question/best answer model. Most "best" questions get closed as *opinion-based*, and questions that admit vagueness have an increased risk of being closed with *unclear what you're asking*.  Please **edit** the question to chose a single solution and focus on that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use some tools that ArcGIS for Desktop offers to run cost analysis. I would find the target area, build a cost raster based on the inputs that you deem to be important (slope, relief, land use, etc.) with self assigned values (creating your own cost for each of those in separate rasters). Once each raster is made with cost values, you can use the raster calculator to add the costs together, and then use the cost distance tool to create a distance raster, and backlink raster using your source points (starting points). Then use the cost path tool and it will follow all of your cost values. The only tedious part is making the rasters, after that you can change the destination points (done within the cost path tool) and rerun the last step to create new routes. The paths you will get will be in raster format, so you can run the feature to line tool to get them to a smooth line.

This requires the spatial analyst license.

Also see: [Understanding cost distance analysis](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000z5000000)

As for using these in Google Maps API, I use the Layer to KML tool to create KML files (which is supported by Google Maps API well) and once they are hosted on a server (I used ArcGIS Online and share them publicly to allow access from my API without issues) you can embed them into the JavaScript file using the KML layer URL. From there you can create toggle events to show what you want.